# Optimizing binary tree gives weird duplication errors

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement an *optimize* method that should make a binary tree complete. My method does this by sorting the tree into an `int*`, then adding the midpoint of the array to a new array and recursing on each half.

However, what the code's actually outputting is generating duplicates after descending to max depth along the left tree:

```
16 8 4 2 1 0 0 3 3 6 5 5 7 7 12 10 9 9 11 11 14 13 13 15 15 24 20 18 17 17 19 19
```

I can't for the life of my figure out why this is happening.

My code:

```
// bth is "binary tree helper [method]"
void bth_optimizearray(int* in, int* out, int min, int max, int* i) {
    // `in' is sorted, `out' should be optimized
    // `i' is the current index in `out'

    int len /* of subarray */ = max - min;
    if (len < 1) {
        // empty subarray
        return;
    }
    if (len == 1) {
        // just add it
        out[(*i)++] = in[min];
    } // else

    // Add the midpoint
    int midpos = min + ((max - min) >> 1);
    out[(*i)++] = in[midpos];
    bth_optimizearray(in, out, min, midpos, i);
    bth_optimizearray(in, out, midpos + 1, max, i);
}

void bt_optimize(bintree *tree) {
    int treesize = bt_size(tree);

    int *ordered = malloc(treesize * sizeof(int));
    {
        int i = 0;
        void visit(node *n) {
            ordered[i++] = n -> key;
        }
        bt_traverse(tree, INORDER, visit);
    }


    int *optimized = malloc(treesize * sizeof(int));
    {
        int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
        (*i) = 0;
        bth_optimizearray(ordered, optimized, 0, treesize, i);
    }

    // Free all nodes (but don't call freetree; that would free the tree too)
    void freenode(node *n) {
        free(n);
    }
    bt_traverse(tree, INORDER, freenode);
    tree -> root = NULL;

    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < treesize; i++) {
            printf("%d ", optimized[i]);
            bt_add(tree, optimized[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, `bintree` is a `struct { node *root; int size; }` and all other methods work as they should.

The full code is also [on GitHub](https://github.com/wchargin/apcs), but this `bt_optimize` method is only in the `optimize` branch.

**This is C, not C++.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when min = max - 1, the "out[(*i)++] statement runs two times.

```
if (len == 1) {
    // just add it
    out[(*i)++] = in[min];
    // -- Should place a "return;" here?
} // else

// Add the midpoint
int midpos = min + ((max - min) >> 1);
out[(*i)++] = in[midpos];
```

Comment: Nice catch! This was a result of failing to fully modify some earlier code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks suspicious to me:

```
out[(*i)++]
```

The reason is this way it will take the value of "i" as index and afterwards it will increment the value.

To prove it i run a test. Example:

```
int index,value;
index = 10;

value = index++;//this way value will become 10 and index 11

index = 10;

value = ++index;//this way both become 11
```

Comment: That's what it should do.

Comment: what about the part "if(len==1){ //code stuff}//else" why is the else only a comment ? either way you sometimes add twice and incrementing the index twice (which should result in a stackoverflow)